# Error with Google Shortener API and Python

Tags: python, json, api, google-url-shortener

I am making an app which works with urls and I need to shorten them. I have written the following code:

```
import requests, json
gUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url'
data = json.dumps({'longUrl': 'http://www.google.es'})
r = requests.post(gUrl, data)
```

It is supposed to be encoded with json, nevertheless, I am getting the following error:

```
print r.json
{u'error': {u'code': 400, u'message': u'This API does not support parsing form-encoded
input.', u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global', u'message': u'This API does not support
parsing form-encoded input.', u'reason': u'parseError'}]}}
```

Other information that may be useful:

```
print r.request
Request [POST]


print r.headers
{'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'expires': 'Thu, 05 Jul 2012 20:47:11 GMT',
'server': 'GSE', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 
'date': 'Thu, 05 Jul 2012 20:47:11 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 
'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make sure that `Content-Type: application/json` is being sent, else the POST data is form encoded.

**eg** `r = requests.post(gUrl, data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}`)

`print r.json` - outputs:

```
{u'kind': u'urlshortener#url', u'id': u'http://goo.gl/5Af0', u'longUrl': u'http://www.google.es/'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is working now. I though the Content-Type was being sent, my fault. Thanks again.